# Ember Serialize 'ID'

Tags: ember.js

I'm making an API call in Ember and the API I'm hitting is returning some JSON with 'ID' capitalized, it seems Ember is looking for lowercase 'id.' Everything else should work, so how would I serialize just this one piece of JSON in this instance?

See JSON below.

`{
    "ID": 2,
    "name": "Main Menu",
    "slug": "main-menu",
    "description": "",
    "count": 4,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 11,
            "order": 1,
            "parent": 0,
            "title": "Contact",
            "url": "http://localhost:8888/contact/",
            "attr": "",
            "target": "",
            "classes": "",
            "xfn": "",
            "description": "",
            "object_id": 7,
            "object": "page",
            "object_slug": "contact",
            "type": "post_type",
            "type_label": "Page"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "order": 2,
            "parent": 0,
            "title": "About",
            "url": "http://localhost:8888/about/",
            "attr": "",
            "target": "",
            "classes": "",
            "xfn": "",
            "description": "",
            "object_id": 5,
            "object": "page",
            "object_slug": "about",
            "type": "post_type",
            "type_label": "Page",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 21,
                    "order": 3,
                    "parent": 12,
                    "title": "About Us – Sub",
                    "url": "http://localhost:8888/about/about-us-sub/",
                    "attr": "",
                    "target": "",
                    "classes": "",
                    "xfn": "",
                    "description": "",
                    "object_id": 9,
                    "object": "page",
                    "object_slug": "about-us-sub",
                    "type": "post_type",
                    "type_label": "Page"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "order": 4,
            "parent": 0,
            "title": "Home",
            "url": "http://localhost:8888/home/",
            "attr": "",
            "target": "",
            "classes": "",
            "xfn": "",
            "description": "",
            "object_id": 2,
            "object": "page",
            "object_slug": "home",
            "type": "post_type",
            "type_label": "Page"
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "links": {
            "collection": "http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/menus/",
            "self": "http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/menus/2"
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `primaryKey: 'ID'` by creating model specific serializer. read more for info https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_ids

Comment: Thanks! Tried this and am getting a new error, one which I have not seen before. How would I navigate this?  ```WARNING: Encountered "ID" in payload, but no model was found for model name "id" (resolved model name using (unknown mixin).modelNameFromPayloadKey("ID"))``` There are a handful of these in relation to the JSON that I showed above (slug, name, etc etc)

Comment: If you are usinv json-api, then you need to follow json-api format.. i think its response data format issue

Comment: I'm using REST on this.

Comment: Yes, seems to be a formatting issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am in phone you can check with rest data format. Make sure you are extending RESTSerializer...